# Speech Recognition: Alternate substrings always empty, confidence 0 most of the time

Tags: ios, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, transcription, sfspeechrecognizer

I'm trying to work with [speech recognition](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech) in iOS, but I guess we're not getting friends...

I've set up an `SFSpeechRegonizer` and set its delegate accordingly. Now I implement the delegate method as follows:

```
func speechRecognitionTask(_ task: SFSpeechRecognitionTask, didHypothesizeTranscription transcription: SFTranscription) {
    print("transcription:         \(transcription.formattedString)")
    print("alternativeSubstrings: \(transcription.segments.map { $0.alternativeSubstrings })")
    print("confidence:            \(transcription.segments.map { $0.confidence })")
}
```

This prints out something as follows whenever the delegate method is called:

```
transcription:         Space – the final frontier. These are the voyages…
alternativeSubstrings: [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
confidence:            [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

The transcription is good. However, the `alternativeSubstrings` arrays are *always* empty and the `confidence` values are 0 most of the time. Every now and then they are non-zero – but it's unpredictable when this happens:

```
confidence:            [0.56, 0.049, 0.558, 0.545, 0.476, 0.6, 0.654, 0.647, 0.829]
```

**Why are there no `alternativeSubstrings`, why is the `confidence` 0 most of the time and how can I fix this?** I Apple's *Speech* library simply broken or what's wrong?